# It is needed to rebuild nvida module after kernel recompilation?

Tags: linux, kernel, nvidia

I'm recompiling kernel testing performance and other stuff, in general all is going well except for the `nvidia` driver, sometimes I modify the kernel just a little, like adding or removing drivers for webcam support and then I go and re-install kernel and modules again, and whenever I do that I need to rebuilt the `nvidia` module, and reinstall all the libraries for `X` and `OpenGL` and `cuda` and so on.

Is there a way to avoid this and just re-use the previously compiled `nvidia` driver, or I have to rebuild the module if the kernel is recompiled ?

Answer (score 0):

if the new kernel has the same name, see if "disabling module signing in the kernel" CONFIG_MODULE_SIG helps

> CONFIG_MODULE_SIG:
>
> Check modules for valid signatures upon load: the signature
> is simply appended to the module. For more information see
> Documentation/module-signing.txt.

i also found this, but don't know if it helps :

> CONFIG_MODVERSIONS:
>
> Usually, you have to use modules compiled with your kernel.
> Saying Y here makes it sometimes possible to use modules
> compiled for different kernels, by adding enough information
> to the modules to (hopefully) spot any changes which would
> make them incompatible with the kernel you are running. If
> unsure, say N.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am building the module against the same kernel tree, just different modules selected, so I am not sure ig the second option is related, in any case I will try both and let you know